# FreeBSD on Beaglebone Black

Tags: freebsd, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to install (or run from MicroSD) FreeBSD on my beaglebone black.

There is a SD card [**image**](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/arm/armv6/ISO-IMAGES/10.3/FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-arm-armv6-BEAGLEBONE.img.xz) at FreeBSD.org and  I downloaded, uncompressed and `dd` it to a microSD. Tried to boot up from this SD by pushing the "boot" button and powering it up, but nothing happens...

Should be straightforward, however, I'm tripping in it. Did a lot of research but couldn't find anything that works!

Did anyone get FreeBSD running in BBB and can give me a "recipe" that works?

Comment: Please edit by adding the exact image used to install freebsd

Comment: Take a look here https://www.freebsdfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/vol1_no1_beaglebone_dkr.pdf

Comment: use a JTAG/serial cable to follow up the boot from the very beginning.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've read the article GAD3R posted here, but for some reason it is still not working. I don't have the cable for serial console... I'm in "blind mode". Should it simply boot?

Comment: Things you should revisit: 1)Are you "pressing" boot button, or "holding" the boot button for 3 seconds while powering up? 2) your `dd` used the right block size (`bs=8m`)? Could be a hell of a help having one of these usb to ttl cables from Adafruit to have a local console to see what is happening - https://www.adafruit.com/product/954